# Removing lag on rendering thousands of entities in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JS canvas. I wanna make a game but when rendering too many (Bricks) the game becomes unplayable. Most of the lag comes from draw function the part where bricks are drawn, From ctx.fill() and ctx.rect() function. I observed it with the chrome's performance devtool.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - ballRadius;
var bulletX = x;
var bulletY = y;
var bullet2X = x;
var bullet2Y = y;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 0;
var paddleWidth = canvas.width;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 50;
var brickColumnCount = 96;
var brickWidth = 5;
var brickHeight = 5;
var brickPadding = 0;
var brickOffsetTop = 0;
var brickOffsetLeft = 0;
var score = 0;
var damageDealth = 0;
var brickHealth = 1000;
var scoreEarned = 0;




window.bricks = [];

if (bricks.length == 0) {
  bricks = [];
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[c] = [];
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      bricks[c][r] = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        status: brickHealth
      };
    }
  }
}
var resetLevel =
  setInterval(() => {
    var brickStatus = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < bricks.length; row++) {
      bricks[row].forEach((status) => {
        if (status.status > 1) {
          brickStatus += 1;
        }

      })
    }

    if (brickStatus < 1) {
      for (var row = 0; row < bricks.length; row++) {
        for (var brick = 0; brick < bricks[row].length; brick++) {
          if (bricks[row][brick].status < 1) {
            brickHealth += 1;
            bricks[row][brick].status = 1000
            allBullets = [];
            childBullets = [];
            AOEBullets = [];
          }

        }
      }
    }
    console.log(brickStatus);
    console.log("BrickHealth: " + brickHealth)
  }, 1000);





document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight" || e.key == "d") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft" || e.key == "a") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }

}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight" || e.key == "d") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft" || e.key == "a") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }


}


function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

class MakeBullet {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color, speedX, speedY, pierce, lifespan, damage) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.pierce = pierce;
    this.lifespan = lifespan;
    this.damage = damage;


  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();

  }
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
    this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
  }
}
window.allBullets = [];
window.childBullets = [];
window.AOEBullets = [];
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  const angle = Math.atan2(event.clientY - y, event.clientX - x);
  window.shootAngle = {
    x: Math.cos(angle),
    y: Math.sin(angle)
  }

})
setInterval(() => {
  if (allBullets.length < 101) {
    allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x, y, 3, "rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9)", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 8, 2, 25))
    /* allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x - 5, y, 3, "rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9)", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 8, 8, 50))
    allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x + 5, y, 3, "rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9)", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 8, 8, 25)) */

  }
}, 75)

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBricks() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      if (bricks[c][r].status > 0) {
        var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  childBullets.forEach((childBullet) => {
    if (childBullet.lifespan > 0) {
      childBullet.update();
      childBullet.draw();

      if (childBullet.x + childBullet.speedX > canvas.width - childBullet.radius || childBullet.x + childBullet.speedX < childBullet.radius) {
        childBullet.speedX = -childBullet.speedX;

      }
      if (childBullet.y + childBullet.speedY > canvas.width - childBullet.radius || childBullet.y + childBullet.speedY < childBullet.radius) {
        childBullet.speedY = -childBullet.speedY;
      } else if (childBullet.y + childBullet.speedY > canvas.height - childBullet.radius) {
        if (childBullet.x > paddleX && childBullet.x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
          if (childBullet.y = childBullet.y - paddleHeight) {
            childBullet.speedY = -childBullet.speedY;


          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
      for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
        var b = bricks[c][r];
        if (b.status > 0) {
          if (childBullet.x > b.x && childBullet.x < b.x + brickWidth && childBullet.y > b.y && childBullet.y < b.y + brickHeight) {
            b.status -= childBullet.damage;
            childBullet.pierce -= 1
            var randomScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            score += randomScore;
            scoreEarned += randomScore;
            damageDealth += childBullet.damage;

          }
        }
      }

    }

  })
  AOEBullets.forEach((AOEBullet) => {
    if (AOEBullet.lifespan > 0) {
      AOEBullet.update();
      AOEBullet.draw();
      for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
          var b = bricks[c][r];
          if (b.status > 0) {
            if (AOEBullet.x + AOEBullet.radius > b.x + brickWidth && AOEBullet.x - AOEBullet.radius < b.x + brickWidth && AOEBullet.y + AOEBullet.radius > b.y + brickHeight && AOEBullet.y - AOEBullet.radius < b.y + brickHeight) {

              b.status -= AOEBullet.damage;
              AOEBullet.pierce -= 1
              var randomScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
              score += randomScore;
              scoreEarned += randomScore;
              damageDealth += AOEBullet.damage;

            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  })



  if (shootAngle !== undefined) {

    allBullets.forEach((bullet) => {

      if (bullet.lifespan > 0) {
        if (bullet.pierce > 0) {
          bullet.update();
          bullet.draw();

          window.BulletX = bullet.x;
          window.BulletY = bullet.y;


          for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
            for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
              var b = bricks[c][r];
              if (b.status > 0) {
                if (bullet.x > b.x && bullet.x < b.x + brickWidth && bullet.y > b.y && bullet.y < b.y + brickHeight) {
                  b.status -= bullet.damage;
                  bullet.pierce -= 1;
                  var randomScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                  score += randomScore;
                  scoreEarned += randomScore;
                  AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 25, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.024)", 0, 0, 5, 0.4, 1.4))
                  AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 50, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.018)", 0, 0, 5, 0.3, 0.7))
                  AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 75, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.016)", 0, 0, 5, 0.2, 0.5))
                  AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 100, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.012)", 0, 0, 5, 0.1, 0.2))
                  damageDealth += bullet.damage;

                }
                if (bullet.x > b.x && bullet.x < b.x + brickWidth && bullet.y > b.y && bullet.y < b.y + brickHeight) {
                  b.status -= bullet.damage;
                }
                if (bullet.x > b.x && bullet.x < b.x + brickWidth && bullet.y > b.y && bullet.y < b.y + brickHeight) {
                  b.status -= bullet.damage;
                }
                if (bullet.x > b.x && bullet.x < b.x + brickWidth && bullet.y > b.y && bullet.y < b.y + brickHeight) {
                  b.status -= bullet.damage;
                }
              }
            }

          }
          if (bullet.x + bullet.speedX > canvas.width - bullet.radius || bullet.x + bullet.speedX < bullet.radius) {
            bullet.speedX = -bullet.speedX;


          }
          if (bullet.y + bullet.speedY > canvas.width - bullet.radius || bullet.y + bullet.speedY < bullet.radius) {
            bullet.speedY = -bullet.speedY;
          } else if (bullet.y + bullet.speedY > canvas.height - bullet.radius) {
            if (bullet.x > paddleX && bullet.x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
              if (bullet.y = bullet.y - paddleHeight) {
                bullet.speedY = -bullet.speedY;



              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    })
  }




  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      if (y = y - paddleHeight) {
        dy = -dy;
      }
    } else {

      document.location.reload();
      clearInterval(interval); // Needed for Chrome to end game
    }
  }

  if (rightPressed && x < canvas.width - ballRadius) {
    x += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && x > 0 + ballRadius) {
    x -= 7;
  }



  // x += dx;
  //y += dy;


}

var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);

setInterval(() => {
  allBullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      var angle = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
      var randomx = bullet.speedX * Math.cos(angle);
      var randomy = bullet.speedY * Math.sin(angle);
      if (bullet.lifespan < 1) {
        AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 25, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.024)", 0, 0, 5, 0.4, 0.24))
        AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 50, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.018)", 0, 0, 5, 0.3, 0.16))
        AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 75, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.016)", 0, 0, 5, 0.2, 0.08))
        AOEBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 100, "rgba(0,149,221, 0.012)", 0, 0, 5, 0.1, 0.04))
        if (childBullets.length < 51) {
          childBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 2, "#0095DD", randomx + randomx * Math.floor(Math.random() * 2), randomy + randomy * Math.floor(Math.random() * 2), 5, 5, 1))

        }
      }
      if (bullet.pierce < 1) {
        if (childBullets.length < 51) {
          childBullets.push(new MakeBullet(bullet.x, bullet.y, 2, "#0095DD", randomx + randomx * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5), randomy + randomy * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5), 5, 5, 1))
        }
      }
    }
  })

}, 1)
var lifeSpan = setInterval(() => {
  allBullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    bullet.lifespan -= 0.1;


  })
  childBullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    bullet.lifespan -= 0.1;


  })
  AOEBullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    bullet.lifespan -= 0.1;


  })
}, 100)
setInterval(() => {

  for (var i = 0; i < allBullets.length; i++) {
    if (allBullets[i].pierce < 1 || allBullets[i].lifespan < 1) {
      allBullets.splice(allBullets.indexOf[i], 1)
    }

  }



}, 50)
setInterval(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < childBullets.length; i++) {
    if (childBullets[i].pierce < 1 || childBullets[i].lifespan < 0) {
      childBullets.splice(childBullets.indexOf[i], 1)

    }
  }




}, 5000)
setInterval(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < AOEBullets.length; i++) {
    if (AOEBullets[i].pierce < 1 || AOEBullets[i].lifespan < 0) {
      AOEBullets.splice(AOEBullets.indexOf[i], 1)

    }
  }




}, 5000)
setInterval(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x, y, 10, "#0095DD", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 10, 3, 5))
    allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x + 10, y, 10, "#0095DD", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 10, 3, 5))
    allBullets.push(new MakeBullet(x - 10, y, 10, "#0095DD", shootAngle.x + shootAngle.x * 12, shootAngle.y + shootAngle.y * 12, 10, 3, 5))
  }

}, 30000)


setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("scrore")[0].innerText = "Score: " + score;
}, 100)
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("scoreEarned")[0].innerText = "Score Earned: " + scoreEarned;
  scoreEarned = 0;
}, 1000)
var damage = setInterval(() => {

  document.getElementsByClassName("damageDealth")[0].innerText = "Damage: " + damageDealth.toFixed(1);
  damageDealth = 0;

}, 1000)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="320" width="480" style="background-color: #eee"></canvas>
<p class="scrore" style="color: rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9); font-family: 'Hammersmith One';">Score: 0</p>
<p class="scoreEarned" style="color: rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9); font-family: 'Hammersmith One';">Score Earned: 0</p>
<p class="damageDealth" style="color: rgba(0, 149, 221, 0.9); font-family: 'Hammersmith One';">Damage: 0</p>
```

Comment: The first thing id do is avoid an entire dom lookup every 100ms for `document.getElementsByClassName("scrore")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea to speed up the drawing is to prepare the next frame to be shown on an invisible canvas. Then blip the invisible canvas to the canvas shown to the player in one go.

```js
// drawing surface
var visibleCanvas_;     // (HTML5 canvas) serves as playfield, visible for user
var visibleCtx2d_;      // (HTML5 canvas 2D context) context of visible canvas
        
// optimization: if drawing with fillRect(), draw on hidden canvas 
var hiddenCanvas_;  // (HTML5 canvas) invisible canvas on which shapes are drawn each step
var hiddenCtx2d_;   // (HTML5 canvas 2D context) context of invisible canvas


function createHiddenCanvas_(mainCanvas) {
    hiddenCanvas_= document.createElement("canvas");
    hiddenCanvas_.width = mainCanvas.width;
    hiddenCanvas_.height = mainCanvas.height;
    hiddenCtx2d_= hiddenCanvas_.getContext("2d");
    // other settings that do not change while drawing, e.g. brick color
    // hiddenCtx2d_.strokeStyle = ...;
    // hiddenCtx2d_.fillStyle = ...;
}

// must be called once at startup of the game
function init_() {
    visibleCanvas_ = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    visibleCtx2d_= visibleCanvas_.getContext('2d');

    createHiddenCanvas_(visibleCanvas_);
}

// to be called before we start building the next frame
function startDraw_() {
    // clear hidden canvas
    hiddenCtx2d_.clearRect(0, 0, hiddenCanvas_.width, hiddenCanvas_.height);
}

// draws single brick for next frame on hidden canvas
function drawBrick_(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight) {
    hiddenCtx2d_.fillRect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
}

// to be called after we finish building the next frame and want to display it
function finishDraw_() {
    // clear visible canvas
    visibleCtx2d_.clearRect(0, 0, visibleCanvas_.width, visibleCanvas_.height);
    // blip hidden canvas on visible canvas
    visibleCtx2d_.drawImage(hiddenCanvas_, 0, 0);
}
```

Draw all shapes for the next frame between `startDraw_` and `finishDraw_`.

You should also look into [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to manage when the next frame is drawn.

Comment: Well, Actually now that I am more experienced in JS a really small fix to this would be to just make it so there is no need to render all the Bricks every frame, Instead just make it so when a Brick is killed removing the dead one from the allBricks array and rendering others back.